# How can I find the package name of the program I want to install?

Tags: command-line, package-management

How does one discover which command to run to install a piece of software?

For example, if I wanted to know the command to run to install VirtualBox, how do I know that I should run `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2`, and not `sudo apt-get install XYZ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't want to use the search field in the Ubuntu Software Center you can search the packages via apt with this command: `sudo apt-cache search virtualbox`

You will get a list of found packages and now you can install it by typing the right package i.e. `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2`

Answer (score 0):

if you do not know which command check the Ubuntu software center first.
because virtualbox is available on the Ubuntu software center.

or check virtual box official website [click here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)
they are saying `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2`